# Commerce Auction same product many auctions

Tags: commerce

I'm working on an auction website using Drupal [Commerce Auction](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auction) module. The requirement is to be able to create several auctions for the same product so that you don't have to create the product again and again.

Is that possible? It seems that the price added to the cart is the product's price. This might be an issue as different auctions for the same product would have different highest bids.

Any thoughts appreciated.