# Adding different auction prices for same product

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm having same issue as [krystalcode's issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59156/commerce-auction-same-product-many-auctions).

First I created a product. Then added the content as auction product. While adding this content, the base price is considered to be the same as the product. So, do I need to add new product before creating an auction item?

It would be great if [farhadhf](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7914/farhadhf), the owner of this [Commerce Auction](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auction) module will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the author of this module or someone else couldn't reply this question, I'm creating new product before creating the content. Then I create the auction content and choose the related product.